# Pandas groupby row wise with unique values

Tags: csv, pandas, plot, row, unique

I am very new to Python and to this page. I tried to search entire web before I decided to write here, please excuse any fault. I am trying to deal with a csv file using Pandas. My csv file values looks something like this (the list you will find when you run the code): (which is normally over 40000 lines but I tried to create a replicate in short version)

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo',  'foo', 'foo', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo',  'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo',  'foo', 'foo'],['5', '10', '15', '20','5', '10', '15', '20','5', '10', '15', '20','5', '10', '15', '20','5', '10', '15', '20','5', '10', '15', '20']]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(24), index=index)
```

I am trying to group the first column arrays as 'bar', 'foo', 'baz' and each of these has column that is '5', '10', '15', '20' with a random value on the third column. When I group the first column, I want to have a plot for each element of the first column which makes 3 separate figures and within each figure, the second column values should display as x values and third column should display as y values. That means that each figure will have multiple line plots for each unique value blocks (that are '5', '10', '15', '20') of second column.

I hope I could explain it enough.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLgkE.png [multiline plot][1]

the figures should display like this for each group 'bar', 'bad', 'foo'. Depending on their number of repetition in the second column values '5', '10', '15', '20', there will be different number of lines in each figure each of which is random as the third column values are random. I was thinking that I could groupby the cvs data and reset_index to change the order of the column rows and then use a for loop for repeating rows which are every 4 rows and plot the third column values but it did not work when I use grouped-reseted index in the for loop. When I group both for unique values of first and second columns, the second column groups itself with'5's together, '10's together etc and the plot becomes something not desired.

Comment: What are you struggling to do?

Comment: Can you post a sketch of the expected output (preferably by setting the seed for randn first).

Comment: when I group the code for first column, it should look like this (please run the code to see, I could not find other ways to write it):
    arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo',  'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo',  'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo',  'foo', 'foo'],['5', '10', '15', '20','5', '10', '15', '20','5', '10', '15', '20','5', '10', '15', '20','5', '10', '15', '20','5', '10', '15', '20']]
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)
    s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(24), index=index)

Comment: 'bar' group should have its own figure, 'foo' should have its own figure and 'baz' should have its own figure. and within each figure, the unique values of second column should be in the x axis in figure, and it should be grouped as '5', '10', '15', '20' with the given values in the third column. This means there will be multiple lines in each figure because second column has repetition every 4 row. These repetitive rows should be separately plotted as line with given values on the third column.